# Drag and drop reset button to original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I wanted to create a reset button to reset the position of my icons back to original position.. I not sure how to start it.. Whenever I drag and drop it is not in the droppable it will went back to the original position.. I want when there is icons inside droppable, when reset button pressed it will reset the position of the icon back to original position.

**jsFiddle**

```
https://jsfiddle.net/xInfinityMing/c0mmbspz/
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="dragIcons">
  <img width="100px" height="100px"src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-uinvert-dock/256/MS_Office_Upload_Center.png">
  <img width="100px" height="100px" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-uinvert-dock/256/MS_Office_Upload_Center.png">
  <img width="100px" height="100px" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-uinvert-dock/256/MS_Office_Upload_Center.png">
  <img width="100px" height="100px" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-uinvert-dock/256/MS_Office_Upload_Center.png">
</div>
<div id="briefcase">
  <div id="briefcase-full">
  </div>
  <div id="briefcase-droppable">
  </div>
</div>
<button id="reset" type="button" onclick="doSomething()">Reset</button>
```

**Java**

```
$(function() {
  $("#dragIcons img").draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  refreshPositions: true,
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    ui.helper.removeClass("end-draggable");
    ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    ui.helper.addClass("end-draggable");
    ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
  }
});
$("#briefcase-droppable").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).parent().css('background-image','url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/yosemite-flat/512/Folder-icon.png")');
    if ($("#briefcase").length == 0) {
      $("#briefcase-droppable").html("");
    }
      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      $("#briefcase-droppable").append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `detach`. when you click `reset` button, it removes image in `briefcase-droppable` and appends into `dragIcons`.

```
$('#reset').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dropped_icon = $('#briefcase-droppable')
        .children()
        .detach()
        .removeClass('dropped end-draggable')
        .removeAttr('style')
        .css('position', 'relative');

    $('#dragIcons').append(dropped_icon);
    $('#briefcase').css('background', 'url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mcdo-design/smooth-leopard/256/Upload-Folder-Blue-icon.png")');
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/c0mmbspz/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Thanks alot!